# Firebase Cloud Function: Return a Base64 string in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase Cloud Function that takes in a URL and convert the contents of the URL (which can be pdf documents/images) into base64 string and return it in a json object. My current implementation encountered the following error message:

> Function execution took 1522 ms, finished with status: 'response error'

No error logs were logged.

My code so far:

```
module.exports = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let url = req.query.url
    return getBuffer(url)
    .then((buf) => {
        let base64String = buf.toString('base64')
        let responseObject = JSON.stringify({'base64': base64String})
        res.status(200).json(responseObject)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error getting buf", err)
    })
});
```

The response object is a valid json (checked with an online json validator) and the base64String looks correct too (ie no invalid characters such as double backslashes).

Advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This seems related to a bug that Google was facing. I would recommend you to contact them on the 1:1 support, so they can assist you better. You can contact them on their [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is doing too much work to generate the response.  If you want to send a serialized JSON for an object, just do this:

```
res.status(200).json({'base64': base64String})
```

The [res.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) method will automatically serialize the string, so you don't have to call JSON.stringify().

Also bear in mind that Cloud Functions limits the total size of the response to 10MB, so if your serialized object is bigger than that, you can expect it will fail.